# Creating components by looping through object

Tags: javascript

I have a state that looks like this

```
this.state = {
    myTests: {
        test1: true,
        test2: true,
        test3: true,
    }
```

}

I want to loop through these values and create components. I'm trying something like this but it's whining that myTests isn't a function. How should I go about it?

```
    let choices = this.state.myTests.map(function(name, value) {
        return (
            <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={value}
                                   onChange={this.handleInput}
                                   name={value}/>}
                label="test"
            />);
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure it's whining that `myTests` isn't a function *here*? There's no reason that error would come from this code since it (`myTests`) isn't being called (e.g., `myTests()`).

Comment: I'm calling it a little further down like this, which might be completely incorrect return (
            <FormGroup row>
                {choices}
            </FormGroup>
        )

Comment: We're not discussing the component, we're discussing `myTests`, because that's what you said it was whining about. Perhaps you could be more explicit in describing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the full complaint is "this.state.myTests**.map** is not a function" which gives a clear picture: the ".map" part is the trigger: you try to use JavaScript's Array.prototype.map() function, but as you can see "this.state.mytests" is an object, and objects have no ".map" function.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices :
Either you loop over with for ... in :
(https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Or you use Object.entries :(https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

You can test :

```
let choices = Object.entries(this.state.myTests).map(function(name, value) {
    return (
        <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox checked={value}
                               onChange={this.handleInput}
                               name={value}/>}
            label="test"
        />);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Array of objects instead?**

You probably wanted `myTests` to be an array of objects instead. Objects do not have `.map()`, but an Array does.

```js
this.state = {
    myTests: [
        { test1: true },
        { test2: true },
        { test3: true },
    ]//, ...
```

**FYI: Loop directly in the `<template>`**

You can create components dynamically in a loop in the template, your JS does not have to do that. Just in case you were missing that fact.